# Is there any option for local database like Sqlite for j2me - CLDC devices?

Tags: database, java-me, cldc

Is there any option for local database like Sqlite for j2me - CLDC devices? 
PerstLite and OpenBaseMovil are both under dual license.
Is there any open source option for this?
Or, any alternate way of developing application.

Comment: [MoSync.com](http://www.mosync.com) also has a SQLite binding, making the implementation cross platform as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from [List of Database in J2ME](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/Java-Micro-Edition/Mobile/List-Database-J-ME):
[Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) - an open source relational database / about 2 megabytes
[Java DB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) - Sun's supported distribution of Apache Derby database / footprint of 2.5 MB
[Floggy](http://floggy.sourceforge.net/) - free object persistence framework for J2ME/MIDP applications / 11k API
[J2MEMicroDB](http://morfeo.upc.es/crom/mod/wiki/view.php?id=16&page=Qu%E8+%E9s+J2MELSDATALIB&gid=0&uid=0) - free object persistence framework for J2ME
[mDrawer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdrawer/) - J2ME generic database program with DES encryption
[RMS DB Class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rms-db-class/) - J2ME class to provide easy access to the RMS-Database system of mobile phones
[Micro DB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/microdb/) -  implementation of relation database in J2ME plataform

For small amount of data you also may use [kXML](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/kxml2/) + [miniXPath](http://minixpath.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Anything specific for Blackberry devices?
UltraliteJ is not open source. Sqlite not available for Blackberry devices...

Comment: Well... UltraliteJ is a part of Sybase SQL Anywhere. It has developer license for 1 machine, so you can develope and test with it for free. but it's commertial and youll have to buy deployement license for delivery. Anyway I heard there will be sqllite support for blackberry in next version, so hold on ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think Floggy is promising. It's frequently updated and it has good documentation. Released under Apache license.