# Is any database available in mobiles , I need a database for making a mobile dictionary app

Tags: database, java-me, mobile

what to use for database , while developing J2ME apps  ? I mean should I use simply txt files or some database like sql is available in mobile phones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices)  may have what you're looking for