# J2ME With Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, java-me

Is there any persistent storage for mobile application of J2me, like SQLite?
If there is then please share the link or some example code of interacting a simple J2ME application with back end persistent database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any option for local database like Sqlite for j2me - CLDC devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is persistent storage for J2ME - called RMS (part of MIDP 2.0) - [look here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=435) for short tutorial. RMS doesn't related to SQL, it's just for persistency.

if you're looking for SQL alike storage - [read this discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME). Hope it would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Perst Lite is McObject’s version of the Perst open source, object-oriented embedded database for mobile and embedded applications on the Java ME platform (also know as Java 2 Platform, Micro Edition or J2ME).

Kindly go through the following link which contains sample program along with details about the database.

http://www.mcobject.com/j2me_database

Check the following link for the list of database supported for JavaME

http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME