# How to handle a big database in j2me

Tags: database, java-me

I want to made one application that use  a database of 400Mb in sqlite3. I looking for sqlite support in j2me but nothing there is a implementation of sqlite sqljet plataform independent but use the `java.io.File` that not exist in j2me. I think that RMS can't handle this capacity.

The db is big but is only one table.

I looking for other format to convert the sqlite db.Database is readonly and can be a resource.

Any ideas?

Comment: 400meg in a midlet! Do it on the server.

Comment: @funkybro Is a telephonic directories in my country the phones don't have access to internet i have to do locally. The app with 400mg Db for android is done and easy to do but for j2me I don't find a option yet even one that not use database at all

Comment: How will you deploy the midlet without Internet access? Alternative idea, split the files into smaller chunks, and bake an index in to the app. Then load the relevant file from file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see list of Database in J2ME [in this thread at JavaRanch forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME). Or you can use [`Perst Lite`](http://www.mcobject.com/j2me_database)(a Java ME embedded database).

I found above links in these questions:
[J2ME With Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940496/j2me-with-sqlite)
[Is there any option for local database like Sqlite for j2me - CLDC devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices)

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer :
 [List of Database in J2ME](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME):

Apache Derby - an open source relational database / about 2 megabytes
Java DB - Sun's supported distribution of Apache Derby database / footprint of 2.5 MB
Floggy - free object persistence framework for J2ME/MIDP applications / 11k API
J2MEMicroDB - free object persistence framework for J2ME
mDrawer - J2ME generic database program with DES encryption
RMS DB Class - J2ME class to provide easy access to the RMS-Database system of mobile phones
Micro DB - implementation of relation database in J2ME plataform

For small amount of data you also may use kXML + miniXPath