# storing Encrypted objects in J2me database

Tags: java-me

i am developing an application which can store encrypted objects in rms & retrieve them is there any API for storing & retrieving the Encrypted objects please suggest me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see list of Database in J2ME [in this thread at JavaRanch forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME). Or you can use [`Perst Lite`](http://www.mcobject.com/j2me_database)(a Java ME embedded database).

I found above links in these questions:
[J2ME With Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940496/j2me-with-sqlite)
[Is there any option for local database like Sqlite for j2me - CLDC devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices)

Others :

Apache Derby - an open source relational database / about 2 megabytes
Java DB - Sun's supported distribution of Apache Derby database / footprint of 2.5 MB
Floggy - free object persistence framework for J2ME/MIDP applications / 11k API
J2MEMicroDB - free object persistence framework for J2ME
mDrawer - J2ME generic database program with DES encryption
RMS DB Class - J2ME class to provide easy access to the RMS-Database system of mobile phones
Micro DB - implementation of relation database in J2ME plataform

For small amount of data you also may use kXML + miniXPath

Comment: thank you 
Polymorphin for your precious reply i will look at those links