# how do i get save, edit, delete, and search ,MIDLET application?

Tags: java, java-me, sql-server-ce, j2mepolish

I am a student. I need to make a application. I have built the GUI. Now I need to know how to do it?

I have heard about sql server compact, but does it work together with j2me? If not, something to solve the problem?

It will be better if you can pass me a example. If you couldn't, not worry, I just to need to know a database program for mobile (with j2me).

Could it be possible without use a database program? For example, using a text file? Or any other storage mechanism.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In j2me you can use [RMS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-rms/). But you can't handle with large data. Some Third party database's also [available](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME) for j2me development. You can use that API's. Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices) existing discussion on same in this forum. And look at [database connection](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/database-connection-using-j2me.html) using j2me article.