# How To connect Local Database in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

How can I connect my local database in my application? I have a database which contains a book. I have to display it in my application in J2ME

Comment: What database? What have you tried so far? Without knowing anything about your application or what you're using, it's difficult to answer.

Comment: i use rms for all DataBase Operation but now i have a already built db and i want to use in my project

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in JME, an app can create a database which is a file stored in the RMS. Actually, there are several APIs that can help you in creating a Java ME database: [Is there any option for local database like Sqlite for j2me - CLDC devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices)

Anyway, I think the data in a sqlite database is not easily accessible to a JME app. It is not impossible but it, maybe, is complicated. Honestly, I don't know anyway to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a server application where you access to database. Also your J2ME has to communicate with your server application for getting Data you want to display (Use HttpConnection Class).

Answer (score -1):

In Mobile Application, you can not directly make connection with local or remote database. To Make Connection with Database , you need a middle tier called a web service. You can create web service in any platform  like Java-Servlet, .net or in PHP. See this is a very simple [example](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.in/2009/02/database-connection-using-j2me.html) to work with MySql Database.

Comment: I have a bulit  database file , i need to ship that database in my application. i am using rms and floggy can i use that already bulit database.

Comment: what kind of database you have ?

Comment: i have .db and .sqlite database files which is already bulit .i need to emmbed in my app in j2me

Comment: can i use databases with these extension in my app

Comment: you mean you have sqlite database in your phone, well I am also doing my other work, so it might be late in reply, when you have rep. 20 or above you can join me in my chat room, see its link in my profile