# best DataBase for a mobile java (J2ME) program

Tags: java, database, mobile, java-me

what is the best `DataBase` for a mobile java program ? `J2ME`

- Used `DB` file outside of `.jar` file of program
- best speed in running query
- have more `SQL` propertise Like `Curser, trigger and ...`
- needed low space (under 1 Mb)
- Other things that is needed for run a high speed java program on every mobile device that have a little amount of space and low speed `prossesor`.

Comment: There are a number of similar questions which you might find useful (one of them is listed below): ["Is there any option for local database like Sqlite for j2me - CLDC devices?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear this question has no real answer.  There are loads of databases you could use and none of us know the problem nearly well enough to give you a solid answer on this issue.  There are countless SQL and NoSQL options for storing data.  Off the top of my head, I would recommend looking at mobile-nosql and perhaps [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788397/is-there-any-option-for-local-database-like-sqlite-for-j2me-cldc-devices).